# Migrate a Node.js Cluster app to StrongLoop ProcessManager

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, strongloop

I'm running on multiple instances a Node.js express web application and api using node `cluster`

My cluster startup file is the typical

```
'use strict';
(function() {

/// node clustering
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var clusterConfig=require('./config/clusterconfig.json');

if (cluster.isMaster) { // master node

    // process=master
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    // Fork workers.
    var maxCPUs = clusterConfig.master.workers;
    maxCPUs=(maxCPUs>=numCPUs)?numCPUs:maxCPUs;

    for (let i = 0; i < maxCPUs; i++) {
        const worker=cluster.fork();
    }

    var masterConfig=require('./config/masterconfig.json');

    // configuration override
    if( process.env.MASTER_PORT ) { // override master port
        masterConfig.http.options.port = process.env.MASTER_PORT;   
    }
    if( process.env.NODE_ID ) { // override node identifier
        masterConfig.pubsub.node = process.env.NODE_ID;  
    }

    var MasterNode=require('./lib/master');
    var master= new MasterNode(masterConfig);
    master.start()
    .then(done=> {
        console.log(`master ${process.pid} started`);
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        console.error("master error",error);
    });
}
else if (cluster.isWorker) { // worker node

    // process=worker
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);

    var workerConfig=require('./config/workerconfig.json');

    // configuration override
    if( process.env.WORKER_PORT ) { // override worker port
        workerConfig.http.options.port = process.env.WORKER_PORT;   
    }
    if( process.env.NODE_ID ) { // override node identifier
        workerConfig.pubsub.node = process.env.NODE_ID;  
    }

    var WorkerNode=require('./lib/worker');
    var worker= new WorkerNode(workerConfig);
    worker.start()
    .then(done=> {
        console.log(`worker ${process.pid} started`);
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        console.error(`worker ${process.pid} error`,error);
    });
}

}).call(this);
```

where I'm running a specified number of workers based on the number of cpus on the server and a configuration.

In my web app logic, the `master` node loads some shared resources once, while the `worker` nodes handles the apis, i.e. a incoming response will be routed from the worker api process to the master node process when those shared resources are required, through a local call.

When using StrongLoop the clustering logic is [implemented](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Clustering) in the process manager, but I'm not sure how to migrate the shared resource logic from my node `cluster` model to the StrongLoop one.